# the FontNames not showing "Full name" for Windows --How can I get the full name for rtf output

Tags: fonts, names

Attempting to determine if a font is available in the system and then encode that font in rtf output, however "the fontnames" shows "Univers Normal" for a font that has a "full name" of "Univers-Light-Normal."

If the rtf uses "Univers Normal" MS Word will not recognize the font in an rtf document.

The Windows Settings:personalization:fonts lists the font as "Univers Normal" but when clicked on, it shows the "Full name" of Univers-Light-Normal which is what Word will recognize.

Is there a way to determine the "full name" of the font?